# list of all project documents?

Tags: resource-planning, project-management-style, documentation

Can someone list down all documents required for project management like planning document, risk management, time plan etc....

Comment: Are you looking at "in-general" kind of documents of  any particular like PMBoK, Agile, or Prince2 or ITIL. This would help to provide you the details.

Comment: looking for in general which defined basic plan for project and can be communicated with stack holder.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a "right" answer, but here are some things that you will almost always want with any approach. Note that if your organization has a PMO, they might have a list of required documents.

1) Project Vision: Some sort of document with the high-level vision of the project/product, what the key value deliveries are, key measures of success, etc. This is the sort of executive summary of why the project is occurring.

2) Communications Plan: Who are the key stakeholders and how will you communicate with them? The how will often vary between approaches. For example, a PMBoK approach will probably be upward status reports while a Scrum team will have a scheduled review session every few weeks for stakeholders, but the plan still exists. Also keep in mind communications with dependencies. How does the team put in requests for the hardware the new system will run on? Any vendor connections?

3) Scope (and I use this term very loosely): Again, this will look very different based on approach. Building an industrial park will probably have a pretty set scope and Work Breakdown Structure. On the other hand, an Agile team will have an evolving backlog. An operations team using Kanban will have a structure and a queue with maybe a few starting service tickets. Whether a Gantt chart or a ticket queue, the current state of this information should always be easily accessible.

This is by no means comprehensive, but these are some of the key things you'll probably always want.

Answer (score 1):

As @Daniel mentioned, there is no direct / right answer as it totally depends on the framework defined by your organization or by your PMO (if you have an Office for the PM!).

The documents can be created from inception to retirement of a project. Though the list can be very very exhaustive, here is my recommendation:

1. Project Due-diligence Report: This document would summarize the details about the project in-terms of vision, mission, size, complexity, viability, and profitability.
2. Project Charter: This document shall contain the details such as project goals, objectives, statement of work, outcome expected from the project, who the stakeholders are, the authority level of a project manager, etc.
3. Project Tailoring: This document shall contain the details about the tailoring process based on the size of the project. For a complex project, most of the documents become mandatory, for a small project, you might need all the documents rather only the nuts and bolts to keep the project going. Hence, this document is required.
4. Project Management Plan: This will include many of the sub-plans like Requirement Management Plan (including the traceability), Work Breakdown Structure (WBS) Plan, Risk Management, Communication Management, Change Management, Procurement Management, Quality Management, Estimation Management, Implementation Management, Knowledge Management, etc
5. Reports: Reports that could help the stakeholders monitor and control the project shall be published. For example, the project status, Risk-Issue-Assumptions log, etc, Project status, Risk-Issue-Assumption report, Phase gating and containment report, etc
6. Operations and Maintenance document: This document will highlight on how the project shall sustain during maintenance mode. How will the project team support during peak hours, seasonal period, etc and will include many other metrics that could show the value-add
7. Induction plan: This document will highlight on how the team members shall be equipped to work on the project - the kind of training, techniques to enable a smoother learning curve
8. Knowledge Management: All the tacit knowledge learned during the project would be recorded for the future. Normally, this activity shall be performed during phase gating and during closure of the project. Irrespective of project failure or success, the PM will need to record the findings to share it with the project stakeholders.

The list can become exhaustive. These documents are very well used in the waterfall, v-process kind of model.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Along with Daniel's answers above of vision, comms and scope, I'd also add the basic docs that you'll need day to day:

- resource tracker (team availability eg holidays - could be a spreadsheet)
- schedule (could be in MS Project)
- work breakdown (eg could be held in jira)
- risk tracker (again, could be a spreadsheet)
- change control